# Qt - Writing a file with QTextStream adds empty new lines to the text

Tags: qt, qstring, qtextstream

I'm using the following code to write some text to a file:

```
QFile caFile(outputFolder + "file.extension");
caFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text);

if(!caFile.isOpen()){
    qDebug() << "- Error, unable to open" << "outputFilename" << "for output";
}
QTextStream outStream(&caFile);
outStream << "First Line\nSecond Line\nThird Line";
caFile.close();
```

**It's working like a charm, but with a little problem ..
The text file should look like this:**

```
First Line
Second Line
Third Line
```

But instead, it looks like this:

```
First Line

Second Line

Third Line
```

What's the problem here?

Comment: You didn't tell us enough details. Where does that text come from?

Comment: @Silicomancer I read it from another file then store it into a QString which I write into my `outStream` .. If I tried to show the QString in a QMessageBox it shows properly ..  So the QString is good.

Comment: You need to provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: @FinalContest Sorry, you're right. Edited.

Comment: Which Operating system?

Comment: @AlaaElrifaie: You really did not provide an SSCCE, but anyway, does my answer work for you?

Comment: @Silicomancer I ran this code under Windows 7 Ultimate

Comment: Strange. Your example code above works fine for me in Windows.

Comment: @Silicomancer Ok please try with the input showed in "Final Contest"'s answer & tell us what happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works for me like a charm.

#### input.txt

```
DA3MTkyMjE0NDdaFw0xODA2MDYyMjE0NDdaMDcxEzARBgNVBAMMCnVqY2E2bjku
anAxEzARBgNVBAoMCnZtamMgMm5vYjMxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG
9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAz0+a0BEJEkPwNq7BEplV81+++wzonVAWWcqe
```

#### main.cpp

```
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QFile>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QByteArray>

int main()
{
    QFile inFile("input.txt");
    inFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text);
    QByteArray inputData = inFile.readAll();

    QFile caFile("output.txt");
    caFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text);

    if(!caFile.isOpen()){
        qDebug() << "- Error, unable to open" << "outputFilename" << "for output";
    }
    QTextStream outStream(&caFile);
    outStream << inputData;
    caFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

#### main.pro

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = main
QT = core
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

#### Build and Run

```
qmake && make && ./main
```

#### output.txt

```
DA3MTkyMjE0NDdaFw0xODA2MDYyMjE0NDdaMDcxEzARBgNVBAMMCnVqY2E2bjku
anAxEzARBgNVBAoMCnZtamMgMm5vYjMxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG
9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAz0+a0BEJEkPwNq7BEplV81+++wzonVAWWcqe
```

Comment: Actually, the same code works with some files perfectly without altering their look, but changes some of them as stated in the question. Weird!

Comment: It could be a matter of encoding or the editor you employ for inspecting the files. See `QIODevice::Text` for reference:  
  
`When reading, the end-of-line terminators are translated to '\n'.   
When writing, the end-of-line terminators are translated to the local   
encoding, for example '\r\n' for Win32.`

Comment: For people coming back to this years later, troubleshooting this depends quite a lot on your text viewer. Notepad might display two lines while Notepad++ will display one line. Use Notepad++ with character visibility on to see what's happening. Usually this happens because the files are getting written with `\r\r\n` instead of `\r\n` on windows because newline characters aren't handled properly (often because you're manually doing it instead of letting Qt do it for you).

Comment: Where will the file be stored on mac book ? I'm not able to find it. Can you please help ? When i give the absolute path to my project dir, it is storing in my project dir. If i give just file name without any path, then i don't know where the file is getting stored.

Answer (score 2):

```
QString filename = "";//file adding path
QFile file(filename);
file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
QTextStream stream(&file);
stream << "abc\nxyz" << endl;
file.close();


output:abc
       xyz
```